# Why is C so much slower than assembly?

Tags: c, performance, assembly

Calculations are inspired by scalar product.
C version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {
    clock_t t0, t1;
    int64_t n = 10000000; // 10 million
    int64_t *m = (int64_t*) malloc ((20*n) * sizeof(int64_t));
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    int64_t sum = 0;
    int64_t k = 0;
    t0 = clock();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += m[k]*m[k+1] + m[k+2]*m[k+3] + m[k+4]*m[k+5] + m[k+6]*m[k+7] + m[k+8]*m[k+9] + m[k+10]*m[k+11] + m[k+12]*m[k+13] + m[k+14]*m[k+15] + m[k+16]*m[k+17] + m[k+18]*m[k+19];
        k += 20;
    }
    t1 = clock();
    printf("%" PRId64 "\n", sum);
    float diff = ((float) (t1 - t0) / 1000000.0F ) * 1000;
    printf("%f", (float) diff);
}
```

Fasm version:

main file:

```
format PE64 console
entry prog

include "win64ax.inc"


section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll', msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess', GetTickCount, 'GetTickCount'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'


section '.text' code readable executable

macro now
{
    cinvoke GetTickCount
    cinvoke printf, <"%lld", 13, 10>, rax
}

prog:

mov r14, temp
mov r15, 10000000 ; 10 million
now
lbl:
dec r15

include "temp_code.asm"
add r14, 80

cmp r15, 0
jne lbl
now

end_prog:
    invoke ExitProcess, 0


section '.data' data readable writeable
    align 8
    temp dq 100000200 dup(0)
```

temp_code.asm:

```
mov rbx, 0
mov rax, [r14 + 0 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 1 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 2 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 3 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 4 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 5 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 6 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 7 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 8 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 9 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 10 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 11 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 12 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 13 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 14 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 15 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 16 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 17 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, [r14 + 18 * 8]
mov rcx, [r14 + 19 * 8]
imul rax, rcx
add rbx, rax
mov rax, rbx
```

Best time for fasm is 93 ms, best time for c with compilation options "gcc.exe -std=c99 -g 1.c -O3 -o 1.exe" is 710 ms. This is 7.63 times slower.
I heard hundreds of times that hand-written assembly cannot beat c compilers, and now this... This is speed of supercar to speed of runner. Your explanations?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201907/discussion-on-question-by-dsblizzard-why-is-c-so-much-slower-than-assembly).

Comment: Are you sure your GCC is making a 64-bit executable?  7.6x slower might be explained by doing 64-bit math in 32-bit mode.

Comment: You're using such a ridiculous amount of memory for your array that I can't even get FASM to build this on Linux (`-m 1024000` isn't large enough, anything larger fails with "failed to allocate memory within 32-bit addressing range" because FASM wants to allocate with `MAP_32BIT`).  Are you sure you're not just testing the difference in page-fault throughput between C `malloc` (after writing it first, even) vs. whatever happens on Windows for that `.data` section?

Comment: If this effectively uses the BSS (not storing all those zeros in the executable file), do they end up all mapped to the same physical page of zeros, leading to data cache hits even though you still get TLB misses?  Does the C version also speed up if you don't write it for initialization, so it stays copy-on-write mapped to a zero page?

Comment: Also, what CPU are you testing on?  With what GCC version?  GCC's asm for the loop is not worse than what you wrote by hand (https://godbolt.org/z/3_El_b). *I heard hundreds of times that hand-written assembly cannot beat c compilers*  This is not true.  You certain *can* when compilers don't do a perfect job ([example](//stackoverflow.com/a/40356449)), it's just not usually worth the effort, and you have to know *exactly* what you're doing.  **The difference in your results is probably from how you allocated memory, not from different loop bodies.** On my Skylake, `gcc -m32` is only 2x slower

Comment: CPU - Athlon II X3 445. gcc - (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0